# Cordova Plugin Camera Preview invokes low quality image in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I get a low quality image while using `cordova plugin camerapreview.startcamera`. Below is my code.

```
 cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera({
    x: 0, 
    y: 0,
    width: screen.width,
    height: screen.height
 }, "back", true, false, false);

 cordova.plugins.camerapreview.takePicture({
     maxWidth:640, 
     maxHeight:640
 });
```